# Inheritance multiple view from base view

Tags: twig, volt

I want to include multiple layout file in `index file of view` and extends all of them from `master.volt`. But my problem is level-1.volt doesn't render when I run `index.volt`. Is my workflow ok? What is the problem?

I have on base view file named `master.volt` that have basic view of my frontend:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center" id="Level-1">
    <div class="col-11">
        <div class="row flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
            {% block bannerOne %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have one view file named `level-1.volt`:

```html
{% block bannerOne %}
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img src="img/pop-1-2.png" class="img-fluid"/>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my `index.volt` view:

```html
{% extends 'master/master.volt' %}
{% include 'layouts/level-1.volt' %}
```

Comment: Included files don't know anything about the blocks of their caller. You would need the code from `level-1.volt` inside `index.volt`

Comment: @DarkBee it works but is any solution exits? i want to seperate files for this?

Comment: I'd suggest using `embed` instead of `include`. With embeds you can change/overwrite the blocks of the embedded file